# Pay Pal Buy Now Button with automated amount change over time?

Tags: dynamic, paypal, paypal-buttons

I want to create a pay pal buy now button that changes the price of my product over time in a preset amount daily. Right now I would have to manual change the price of saved buttons in Paypal.

In the call me crazy department I also would like to be able to link a price (in my case original artwork) of my product to a function that calculates the price of a product (in this case DJIA divided by X times per square foot total size of the painting... but that's just for fun as the fine art market can be very arbitrary in pricing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with a hosted button unless you're using the Button Manager API.  If you're going to use API's, though, I'd recommend going with Express Checkout.  You could hook this up to a database or just have your script calculate whatever it needs to dynamically populate the request data including the amount or anything else necessary.